# Use @viewchild in a 2d array

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to print a 10x10 grid in my HTML. To do so, I use two ngFor in my html. In my TypeScript component, I want to access a cell of this table with @ViewChild to put the caret of the cursor in it. I know how to access it with document.getElementById, but I need help for the @ViewChild.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of crosswordDataService?.grid?.boxArray; let i = index">
  <input class="number" value="{{i+1}}" disabled>
  <div class="cell" *ngFor="let col of crosswordDataService?.grid?.boxArray; let j = index">
    <input type="text" id="{{i}}_{{j}}" class="box" maxLength="1" }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code with document.getElementById

```
public setCaretPosition(idElement: string): void {
    const ctrl: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(idElement);
    const pos: number = (ctrl as HTMLInputElement).value.length;
    if ((ctrl as HTMLInputElement).setSelectionRange) {
        (ctrl as HTMLInputElement).focus();
        (ctrl as HTMLInputElement).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ViewChildren` to access elements with a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-), as shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-nq22v8).

A template reference variable `#box` is set on the input elements:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of crosswordDataService?.grid?.boxArray; let i = index">
  <input class="number" value="{{i+1}}" disabled>
  <div class="cell" *ngFor="let col of crosswordDataService?.grid?.boxArray; let j = index">
    <input #box type="text" id="{{i}}_{{j}}" class="box" maxLength="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

and the elements are retrieved with `@ViewChildren` in the code. You can then use the `find` method of the `QueryList` to get the input element that has a specific `id`.

```
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChildren("box") boxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  public setCaretPosition(i: number, j: number): void {
    const id = `${i}_${j}`;
    const inputRef = this.boxes.find(box => box.nativeElement.id === id);
    const input = inputRef.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    input.focus();
    ...
  }
}
```

Note: the `QueryList` may not be populated yet in `ngOnInit` or in other early events. You can subscribe to `this.boxes.changes` to be notified when the list is ready.